# Identify time gaps in date entries with START and END columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've been tasked with finding gaps between time ranges within the day in an effort to understand our daily scheduling problems.  I see a lot of discussion on this topic and it seems well-established that cursors are generally to be avoided, which is a shame because I understand how to do those.

Consensus seems like recursive CTE are the approach to take and examples of those are abundant, but are based on different source data structure than mine, often spanning larger periods of time and looking at the "day" granularity instead of by minute (I am working with 15 minute intervals, but this is subject to change).  Here's a sample of the source data I am working with:

[image]

My interest is solely in finding the gaps in the schedule between MIN(STARTTIME) and MAX(ENDTIME) for that day, and writing those gaps to another table.  Since I have some pretty quick queries that view the data when provided in the above-pictured format, I want whatever solution I have to INSERT into a supplementary table in the same format.

One effort I made:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('#test', 'U') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #test

CREATE TABLE #test (
daterow int IDENTITY,
obj_id int,
datestart datetime,
dateend datetime
);

INSERT INTO #test
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 07:00:00',
'2014-12-14 08:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 09:00:00',
'2014-12-14 09:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 10:00:00',
'2014-12-14 11:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 12:00:00',
'2014-12-14 14:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
2,
'2014-12-14 07:00:00',
'2014-12-14 07:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
2,
'2014-12-14 08:00:00',
'2014-12-14 10:45:00';


WITH C1 AS (
        SELECT obj_id, ts, Type
            ,e=CASE Type WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id, Type ORDER BY dateend) END
            ,s=CASE Type WHEN -1 THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id, Type ORDER BY datestart) END
        FROM #test
        CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES (1, datestart), (-1, dateend)) a(Type, ts)
        ),
    C2 AS (
        SELECT C1.*
            ,se=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY ts, Type DESC)
        FROM C1),
    C3 AS (
        SELECT obj_id, ts
            ,grpnm=FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY ts)-1) / 2 + 1)
        FROM C2
        WHERE COALESCE(s-(se-s)-1, (se-e)-e) = 0),
    -- C1, C2, C3, C4 combined remove the overlapping date periods
    C4 AS (
        SELECT obj_id, datestart=MIN(ts), dateend=MAX(ts)
        FROM C3
        GROUP BY obj_id, grpnm)
SELECT obj_id, datestart=MIN(newdate), dateend=MAX(newdate)
FROM (
    SELECT obj_id, newdate
        ,rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_id ORDER BY newdate) / 2
    FROM C4 a
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES (datestart-1),(dateend+1)) b(newdate)
    ) a
GROUP BY obj_id, rn
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY obj_id, datestart;
```

Resulted in this output:

[image]

The results are all wrong, but I feel like it might make more sense in the morning.  Maybe somebody can reveal my fatal flaws?

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: @n8 What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: If you can conceive of a solution that uses cursors, then use them. Be pragmatic - cursors can be slow and resource intensive, but there is definitely a place for them in some cases that are just way harder to solve in a set-oriented way.

Comment: @n8 are you expecting overlapping data as in your sample data?

Comment: @NoDisplayName: The expected output should be the same format as the input.

Comment: @SteveFord I'm using 2008 R2, there is no overlap.

Comment: @Rikalous thanks for the encouragement.  I may try both ways or a combination thereof.  Speed is of the utmost importance as this will be utilized by end-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test data, and resulted output is not the same, so it makes it very difficult to understand what it is you're looking for, however, here's my understanding

Using your test data...

```
obj_id     datestart            dateend
1          2014-12-14 07:00:00.000  2014-12-14 08:45:00.000
1          2014-12-14 09:00:00.000  2014-12-14 09:45:00.000
1          2014-12-14 10:00:00.000  2014-12-14 11:45:00.000
1          2014-12-14 12:00:00.000  2014-12-14 14:45:00.000
```

There is a timelslot missing for row 1 from 8:45, to 9:00 when the next start time is..
So you would expect to see a "time gap" starting at 8:45 to 9:00. The same for 9:45 to 10:00 in the next row... and so on. Is that correct?

```
obj_id     datestart            dateend
1          2014-12-14 07:00:00.000  2014-12-14 08:45:00.000
1          2014-12-14 08:45:00.000  2014-12-14 09:00:00.000 <missing>
1          2014-12-14 09:00:00.000  2014-12-14 09:45:00.000
1          2014-12-14 09:45:00.000  2014-12-14 10:00:00.000 <missing>
1          2014-12-14 10:00:00.000  2014-12-14 11:45:00.000
1          2014-12-14 11:45:00.000  2014-12-14 12:00:00.000 <missing>
1          2014-12-14 12:00:00.000  2014-12-14 14:45:00.000
```

This query...

```
SELECT a.obj_id, a.dateend as datestart, 
ISNULL(
    (SELECT TOP 1 c.datestart
    FROM #test c
    WHERE c.obj_id = a.obj_id
    AND c.datestart > a.dateend
    ORDER BY c.datestart), GETDATE()) dateend
FROM #test a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM #test b
    WHERE a.obj_id = b.obj_id
    AND a.dateend = b.datestart)
AND EXISTS(
SELECT NULL
FROM #test c
WHERE c.obj_id = a.obj_id
AND c.datestart > a.dateend)
```

Produces this result....

```
obj_id     datestart            dateend
1          2014-12-14 08:45:00.000  2014-12-14 09:00:00.000
1          2014-12-14 09:45:00.000  2014-12-14 10:00:00.000
1          2014-12-14 11:45:00.000  2014-12-14 12:00:00.000
```

All the missing slots from your test data... (for obj_id = 1)

Hope that helps

Comment: This works with my data set, I can modify it for my purposes, and it is very fast, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to SQL Server 2012 or later you can use `LEAD`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0313f/23)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
daterow int IDENTITY,
obj_id int,
datestart datetime,
dateend datetime
);

INSERT INTO test
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 07:00:00',
'2014-12-14 08:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 09:00:00',
'2014-12-14 09:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 10:00:00',
'2014-12-14 11:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
1,
'2014-12-14 12:00:00',
'2014-12-14 14:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
2,
'2014-12-14 07:00:00',
'2014-12-14 07:45:00'
UNION
SELECT
2,
'2014-12-14 08:00:00',
'2014-12-14 10:45:00';
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '20141215 00:00:00'
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20141214'
;WITH gaps
AS
(
   SELECT T.obj_id, 
          T.DateEnd As DateStart, 
          LEAD(T.DATESTART, 1, @EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY T.obj_id ORDER BY T.DateRow) AS DateEnd
   FROM TEST T

),
minStart
AS
(
   SELECT obj_id, MIN(@StartDate) As DateStart, MIN(DateStart) AS DateEnd
   FROM TEST
   GROUP BY obj_id
   HAVING MIN(@StartDate) < MIN(DateStart)  
  )
SELECT obj_id, DateStart, DateEnd
FROM gaps
WHERE DATEDIFF(mi, DateStart, DateEnd) > 0
UNION 
SELECT obj_id, DateStart, DateEnd
FROM minStart
ORDER BY obj_id, DateStart
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0313f/23/0)**:

```
| OBJ_ID |                       DATESTART |                         DATEEND |
|--------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|
|      1 | December, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 | December, 14 2014 07:00:00+0000 |
|      1 | December, 14 2014 08:45:00+0000 | December, 14 2014 09:00:00+0000 |
|      1 | December, 14 2014 09:45:00+0000 | December, 14 2014 10:00:00+0000 |
|      1 | December, 14 2014 11:45:00+0000 | December, 14 2014 12:00:00+0000 |
|      1 | December, 14 2014 14:45:00+0000 | December, 15 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
|      2 | December, 14 2014 00:00:00+0000 | December, 14 2014 07:00:00+0000 |
|      2 | December, 14 2014 07:45:00+0000 | December, 14 2014 08:00:00+0000 |
|      2 | December, 14 2014 10:45:00+0000 | December, 15 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: Sadly I do not have 2012, but thank you for the insight.